# How to get the next month when click on button in android?

Tags: android

In my application i have a text view to set the current month and two buttons for next month and previous month.  When click on next button i need to set the next month to text view without opening the month picker and similarly to previous button also.  Please can any one help me.

Comment: what you have `tried` post that code first ?

Comment: show us some efforts !

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
int next_month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int prev_month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the name of the next month:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
String name = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some methods like getMonth()-This method gets the selected month.This will helpful to find the present month then change month according to buttons previous or next by adding some functions.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button previous,nextmonth;
    TextView calenderview;
    private int year, month, day;
    private Calendar calendar;
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
            nextmonth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
            calenderview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calender);
           calenderview.setText(getCurrentDate());
            previous.setOnClickListener(this);
            nextmonth.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    public String getCurrentDate(){
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Current Month: ");
        builder.append(Calendar.MONTH);
        return builder.toString();
    }
    private String getnextmonth() {
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Previous Month: ");
        builder.append(Calendar.MONTH+1);
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String getpreviousmonth() {
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Next Month : ");
        builder.append(Calendar.MONTH-1);
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.previous_button:
                calenderview.setText(getpreviousmonth());

                break;
            case R.id.next_button:
                calenderview.setText(getnextmonth());
                break;
        }
    }


}
```